# Accessing the facebook details without opening the Facebook Dialog in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am trying to access the user information like gender,age,martial status,ethnicity without opening the Facebook dialog.At present i am having the access token and Facebook id with me,now i want to access the above information which i have mentioned above without opening the Facebook dialog when the application is reopened, Can any one suggest me how to approach it or tell me is it possible or not
                            Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can get all urls
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/coreconcepts/

by this url
[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=yr app id](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=100000462326257)

```
 you can get these details
{
  "id": "dasgadsksfdkjasd",
  "name": "Allone M Hiveone",
  "first_name": "Allone",
  "middle_name": "M",
  "last_name": "Hiveone",
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/id.emaifhfshd",
  "username": "id.emai",
  "birthday": "01/03/1982",
  "location": {
    "id": "115440481803904",
    "name": "Ahmedabad, India"
  },
  "gender": "male",
  "relationship_status": "In a relationship",
  "email": "dddff@gmail.com",
  "timezone": 5.5,
  "locale": "en_US",
  "verified": true,
  "updated_time": "2012-02-21T10:01:17+0000",
  "type": "user"
}
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/  open your account and search for explorer then you can provide id to the following utl it will work

Answer (score 0):

you have to get permission like this ..

```
    userDictionary = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"USER_INFO"];
    [lblDOB setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:[self.userDictionary valueForKey:@"birthday"]]];
    [lblName setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:[self.userDictionary valueForKey:@"first_name"]]];
    [lblGender setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:[self.userDictionary valueForKey:@"gender"]]];
    [lblEmail setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:[self.userDictionary valueForKey:@"email"]]];
    NSString *userIDString = [NSString stringWithFormat:[self.userDictionary valueForKey:@"id"]];

   UIImage *imageIcon = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=normal",userIDString]]]];
    [userImg setImage:imageIcon];
    searching = NO;
  letUserSelectRow = YES;
```